# Masking layer vs attention_mask parameter in MultiHeadAttention

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transformer-model

I use `MultiHeadAttention` layer in my transformer model (my model is very similar to the named entity recognition models). Because my data comes with different lengths, I use padding and `attention_mask` parameter in `MultiHeadAttention` to mask padding. If I would use the `Masking` layer before `MultiHeadAttention`, will it have the same effect as `attention_mask` parameter? Or should I use both: `attention_mask` and `Masking` layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tensoflow documentation on [Masking and padding with keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding) may be helpful.
The following is an excerpt from the document.

> When using the Functional API or the Sequential API, a mask generated
> by an Embedding or Masking layer will be propagated through the
> network for any layer that is capable of using them (for example, RNN
> layers). Keras will automatically fetch the mask corresponding to an
> input and pass it to any layer that knows how to use it.

tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention also supports automatic mask propagation in [TF2.10.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.10.0).

> Improved masking support for tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention.

> - Implicit masks for query, key and value inputs will automatically be
>   used to compute a correct attention mask for the layer. These padding
>   masks will be combined with any attention_mask passed in directly when
>   calling the layer. This can be used with tf.keras.layers.Embedding
>   with mask_zero=True to automatically infer a correct padding mask.

> - Added a use_causal_mask call time arugment to the layer. Passing
>   use_causal_mask=True will compute a causal attention mask, and
>   optionally combine it with any attention_mask passed in directly when
>   calling the layer.

Answer (score 0):

The masking layer keeps the input vector as it and creates a masking vector to be propagated to the following layers if they need a mask vector ( like RNN layers). you can use it if you implement your own model.If you use models from huggingFace, you can use a masking layer for example if you you want to save the mask vector for future use, if not the masking operations are already built_in, so there is no need to add any masking layer at the beginning.